# Ubuntu MATE is not recognizing my WiFi network card

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo

I am trying an Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on a quite old laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad X201). It seems that the WiFi card is not being recognized by the system.

```
lshw -C network
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Use text Cut-and-Paste, don't insert images. Did you not read the `WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.` message? The `*-network DISABLED` hints that you have a HARDWARE switch set to "OFF No WiFi". Look at the results of `rfkill list`, and find that physical switch.

Comment: What is the position of the wireless radio switch? https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd025703

Comment: I forgot to mention that the WiFi switch is ON